# How to ignore/skip functions and methods when using Reflection in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, reflection, phpdoc

I am building a multiprotocol webservice using `Zend_JSON_Server` and `Zend_XmlRpc_Server` using PHP 5.2.6. and I am currently facing the problem, that the server is now announcing every single method from my classes and its parents.

```
class MyClass extends MyInterface {
  /**
   * To be published and accessible
   **/
  public function externalUse() {}
}

class MyInterface {
  /**
   * This method should not be published using the webservice,
   * but needs to be of type "public" for internal use
   * @access private
   * @ignore
   **/
   public function internalUseOnly() {}
}

$server = new Zend_Json_Server();
$server->setClass('MyClass');

// show service map
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$server->setTarget('/service.json')
       ->setEnvelope(Zend_Json_Server_Smd::ENV_JSONRPC_2);

$smd = $server->getServiceMap();
die($smd);
```

This code will also announce `internalUseOnly` as an accessible function using the webservice:

```
{ "SMDVersion" : "2.0",
  "contentType" : "application/json",
  "envelope" : "JSON-RPC-2.0",
  "methods" : { "externalUse" : { "envelope" : "JSON-RPC-2.0",
          "parameters" : [  ],
          "returns" : "null",
          "transport" : "POST"
        },
      "internalUseOnly" : { "envelope" : "JSON-RPC-2.0",
          "parameters" : [  ],
          "returns" : "null",
          "transport" : "POST"
        }
    },
  "services" : { "externalUse" : { "envelope" : "JSON-RPC-2.0",
          "parameters" : [  ],
          "returns" : "null",
          "transport" : "POST"
        },
      "internalUseOnly" : { "envelope" : "JSON-RPC-2.0",
          "parameters" : [  ],
          "returns" : "null",
          "transport" : "POST"
        }
    },
  "target" : "/service.json",
  "transport" : "POST"
}
```

As you can see I already tried `@ignore` and `@access private`, but both are ignored by Reflection. Is there any other option to remove such functions from my service map?

Thanks in advance!

---

***Update***

One solution I found is to make private / protected methods accessible again using overloading and dynamic function calls. But as `call_user_func` is not known to be one of the fasted methods around, this is only meant to be a hotfix.

```
class MyInterface {
    public function __call($method, $params) {
        $method = '_' . $method;
        if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
            call_user_func(array($this, $method), $params);
        }
    }

  /**
   * This method should not be published using the webservice,
   * but needs to be of type "public" for internal use
   * @ignore
   * @access private
   * @internal
   **/
  protected function _internalUseOnly() { die('internal use only!'); }
}
```

Comment: some result unfortunately. But thanks for the keyword, I didn't know about it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix your methods with __. Zend\Server\Reflection\ReflectionClass ignore methods starting by __. At least in ZF2.